# keep the first element vertically centered with the next elements following below

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three elements currently vertically centered in a container through flex:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 800px;
}
```

Looking like:
[image: code sample]

I would like to change it so the first element is vertically centered and the other elements follow:
[image: code sample]

Ideally this could be done simply through flex but so far I cannot find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: do your elements have a fixed size?

Comment: @jcal no the element sizes are not fixed

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have a fixed size, you could accomplish this with a wrapping div
which size is the same as the first element and let the following elements just overflow.

```css
.parent {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-container,
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.second {
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item first">A</div>
    <div class="item second">B</div>
    <div class="item third">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML structure, it's possible: Put the second and third elements  into a wrapper DIV and put that one into the first. Then center the first one (not necessarily with flex - see below) and apply `position: relative` to it, and apply `position: absolute` and according position settings to the wrapper. For details see the snippet below.

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.first {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.second {
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
}

.third {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">A
    <div class="wrap1">
      <div class="second">B</div>
      <div class="third">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ADDITION: Actually it's also possible with flex:

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.second {
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
}

.third {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">A
    <div class="wrap1">
      <div class="second">B</div>
      <div class="third">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```